# Encoding accented letters in DataWeave mule 4

Tags: encoding, dataweave, mule4

I've a problem to send a body http containing accented letters correctly to an external api with body json? I have a problem with encoding
I followed this link without success: [Encoding accented letters in DataWeave](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Encoding-accented-letters-in-DataWeave)

currently I'm developing on windows 10 and actually, in the anypoint console I read at the startup of the app:

- Application: manager_cni_desknet-2 *
- OS encoding: windows-1252, Mule encoding: UTF-8

the configuration of the http connector is the one in the picture [httprequest configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8XTp.png) but the string "�ndice" continues to be sent and the remote API responds with error 422 (the body json is incorrectly formatted) .

Since the production environment is Linux, can you tell me if this is only a windows problem, since Linux uses encoding utf-8 as a mule?

Thank you all

Comment: Please use code sample formatting and not screenshots

Comment: Also enable HTTP wire logging and attach the output so we can see how the HTTP request is being encoded: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-HTTP-Wire-Logging

Comment: Have you tried calling your external API manually using any REST API client and see if it is successful with accented characters? If yes, you need to check the encoding you used to send the successful body and use that in your mule application. It might be that your external API has some restriction on character encoding and cannot parse/read the body you are sending.

Comment: Have you tried other encodings?

Comment: I understood that anypoint inherits from windows that uses encoding 1252 while the mule runtime uses encoding utf-8, it is not a big problem since the development environment is Linux that uses utf-8, I could not find a solution for anypoint below windows

Comment: I ignored the problem precisely because in development environment the encoding is utf-8. thank you all